# PHP APC Accelerator completely breaks Apache2 on Windows?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, php, alternative-php-cache

My local development configuration:

- **Apache 2.2.21** VC9 downloaded from [Apache Lounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/) (as suggested at [PHP For Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/) website. Manual installation as service.
- **PHP 5.3.8 VC9 x86** Thread Safe, installed manually from the zip file.
- **PHP APC 20110109-5.3-vc9-x86** downloaded from [here](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/), then i added `extension=php_apc.dll` to my `php.in`.
- Xdebug PHP 5.3 VC9 TS (32 bit), if relevant

**Result**: sometimes page hangs and i must restart Apache manually from services panel. Anyone lese experienced this? Is my configuration wrong? THis is happening even with a simple `phpinfo` page:

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

Comment: Some log output would greatly help.  First thing that comes to mind is some sort of PHP error is happening but not being displayed.  What are your error logging/display settings?

Comment: I agree, this is not enough info.

Comment: Btw, I'm not saying APC is not to blame, but before you blame a specific extension, I'd disable all others (especially xdebug) and try one by one if you can reproduce the hangs.

Comment: Please have a look at my comment on http://serverfault.com/a/407436/128197. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

APC and xdebug generally don't play well together in my experience.  I suspect it will run fine with APC if you disable xdebug.

Answer (score 0):

Start by ruling out Apache - call 'php -m' to get a list of modules and see how responsive that is.

If it's slow, then you know PHP is to blame. 
Disable every module and enable each one at a time, running php -m to check response.

Pre 5.3.8 the curl extension caused similar woes, but that was corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the apc.php file from apc package and use it to see how your APC is using memory.

Give it lot of ram, until he has 20% unused.